# Reading a csv file into a Pandads dataframe with more than one separator for the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a a csv-file that has as separator the comma sign and at the same time values are separated by ". The first line is text, the second line is empty and the third line consists of column headings. If I try to import the file into a dataframe using pandas with using the code

```
IE00B0M62Q58 = pd.read_csv('ETF/sample.csv', sep=',')
```

I get an error like

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 13
```

How can I read the file into a dataframe in Pandas?

I copied and pasted the sample.csv file which looks as follows:

```
Fondsposition per,"03.Jun.2021"


Emittententicker,Name,Anlageklasse,Gewichtung (%),Kurs,Nominale,Marktwert,Nominalwert,Sektor,ISIN,Börse,Standort,Marktwährung
"AAPL","APPLE INC","Aktien","3,63","123,54","1.722.459","212.792.585","212.792.584,86","IT","US0378331005","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"MSFT","MICROSOFT CORP","Aktien","3,08","245,71","735.512","180.722.654","180.722.653,52","IT","US5949181045","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"AMZN","AMAZON COM INC","Aktien","2,38","3.187,01","43.863","139.791.820","139.791.819,63","Zyklische Konsumgüter ","US0231351067","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"FB","FACEBOOK CLASS A INC","Aktien","1,37","326,04","245.671","80.098.573","80.098.572,84","Kommunikation","US30303M1027","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
"GOOG","ALPHABET INC CLASS C","Aktien","1,24","2.404,61","30.223","72.674.528","72.674.528,03","Kommunikation","US02079K1079","NASDAQ","Vereinigte Staaten","USD"
```

Comment: I tried to edit the text to have formatting, but it was unclear in the initial formatting if `Fondsposition per,"03.Jun.2021"` is in the sample.csv or not.

Comment: Thank you, yes "Fondsposition per,"03.Jun.2021" is the first line, I would delete the line afterwards I managed to read the csv-file into a dataframe, but I was not able to get it into a dataframe because of the two separators , and ".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `decimal` parameter in your call

`IE00B0M62Q58 = pd.read_csv('ETF/sample.csv', sep=',', decimal=',')`

Also if `.` it is a digit separator and `2.404,61` is `2404.61`, then you can use the `thousands` parameter:

`IE00B0M62Q58 = pd.read_csv('ETF/sample.csv', sep=',', decimal=',' thousands='.')`

Add skiprows if you want to skip reading specific rows at the beginning

```
IE00B0M62Q58 = pd.read_csv('ETF/sample.csv', sep=',',skiprows=2, thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it works perfectly. The only thing i dont undertand why we dont need to consider the ", but it works anyway. And i need to skip the first 2 linesby using skiprow=2 IE00B0M62Q58 = pd.read_csv('ETF/sample.csv', sep=',',skiprows=2, thousands='.', decimal=',')